# Ad a badge to buddyboss user profile for members with active pmpro subscription (Wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, integration, membership, badge, buddypress

I am using **BuddyBoss** and **Paid Membership Pro**, I have installed the **Paid Memberships Pro - BuddyPress & BuddyBoss Add On** plugin too.

In **PMPRO** I have only one plan with ID 2.

I want to add on the members list and on the profile page a badge that says **PRO** only for users that have active the **PMPRO** plan.

[image]

[image]

I have tried this

```
function pro_member_badge () {
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    if(pmpro_hasMembershipLevel ('2', $user_id)) {
        ?>
        <span class='pro-member-badge' data-balloon-pos="up" data-balloon="Pro Member">
            <img src="https://ecastify.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/05/pro-budge.png">
        </span>
        <?php
    }
    else {
        ?>
        <span class='pro-member-badge' data-balloon-pos="up" data-balloon="Pro Member">
            <p>No Membership</p>
        </span>
        <?php
    }
}
add_action( 'bp_member_members_list_item', 'pro_member_badge' );
// add_action( 'bp_profile_field_item', 'pro_member_badge' );
```

But this gets the current user subscription and adds it everywhere.
I want to check every users subscription and show the badge only to the users with active the plan with ID 2.

Any ideas?

Thanks!
Sry about my English and my code, they are bad :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$user_id = bp_get_member_user_id();
```

Comment: Oh my god!!! I've been struggling for 3 days now. Thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Btw, I found the hook for adding the badge to the members list with this
add_action( 'bp_member_members_list_item', 'pro_member_badge' );
How can I add it to the user profile and activity? Do you know the hooks?

Comment: If you found the answer useful, please click the green checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

About your Question to input in user profile, put this

```
  add_action('bp_before_member_header_meta', 'pro_member_badge');
```